# CSS Navigation Menu Won't Resize

Tags: css

Website: www.medtransportcenter.com

The navigation menu is pure CSS, built with CSS3 Menu software. The menu on the site displays but the sizes for each element are off. I've been trying to make each element more even (around 140-150px width / height is fine), for instance you can see the Comments is much wider than the others (252px x 50px).

I've tried manually overriding the width in a separate stylesheet for the Comments element:

```
li#menu-item-139.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.menu-item-139 {
  width: 140px;
}
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work and I'm stuck on how to fix it. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Lines 42 through 51 contain the styles for the menu items. Get rid of the `width`s for the individual items. Whatever software made this stylesheet is horrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are `%` widths set in the stylesheet  like

```
ul#css3menu11>li:nth-child(4) {
width: 26%;
```

basically you need to play with them or just remove them.

Comment: `!important` is a last resort. I wouldn't recommend it when you can still edit the stylesheet.

Comment: @Blender yeah i know. i hate using it. but sometimes its the only way out.

Comment: @mc1010 i will look at the source than. see if i can find some way.

Comment: Thank you, looks like that is problem. I edited them and it worked, although my cache for my site is screwed up so it doesn't update right away.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ul` from `inline-table` to `inline-block`, also change your `li` from `table-cell` to `inline-block`. Then readjust the `width` of the `menu`.